# Why is.double() returns a factor variable?

Tags: r, double, dplyr

The `is.double()` function returns a `factor` variables. Here is the code and it's output:

```
df <- data.frame(City = c("A","B","A","C","A","B"), 
Empl = c(3,6,3,2,6,8), UnEmpl = c(4,7,5,6,3,1))

select_if(df, is.double)
```

This is what we get, all `double` variables are returned:

```
Empl UnEmpl
<dbl> <dbl>
3   4           
6   7           
3   5           
2   6           
6   3           
8   1
```

after some operations

```
df <- df %>% group_by(City) %>% mutate(total = sum(Empl,UnEmpl))
select_if(df, is.double)
```

This is what we get, `city` is a `factor` variable but still returned by the function `is.double()`

```
City    Empl  UnEmpl total
<fctr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
A   3   4   24  
B   6   7   22  
A   3   5   24  
C   2   6   8   
A   6   3   24  
B   8   1   22
```

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. The grouping variables are always returned in the result, regardless of its class. If you don't want city, `ungroup` before applying `select_if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The documentation of `select_if()` explicitly says the grouping variables are always retained. You can also check [this Github page](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3480) from the authors of **dplyr**. Eventually, ungrouping the new `df` with `ungroup()` does the trick.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(City = c("A","B","A","C","A","B"), 
                 Empl = c(3,6,3,2,6,8), 
                 UnEmpl = c(4,7,5,6,3,1))

select_if(df, is.double)

> select_if(df, is.double)
  Empl UnEmpl
1    3      4
2    6      7
3    3      5
4    2      6
5    6      3
6    8      1

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(City) %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(Empl,UnEmpl))

> select_if(ungroup(df), is.double)
  Empl UnEmpl total
1    3      4    24
2    6      7    22
3    3      5    24
4    2      6     8
5    6      3    24
6    8      1    22
```

To conclude, what you observe is the intended behavior.

Comment: Converting to a data.frame removes the grouping attribute of the tibble. I wouldn't be so quick to report this as a bug. ;)

Comment: Can't you recover it afterwards? Anyway this could be true, though it doesn't explain why the predicate in `select_if()` doesn't return what you are asking when using a `tibble`.

Comment: I'd say not. Data.frames don't have a "Groups" attribute. And tibbles are not standard R objects. As I said above, the "groups" variables are included in all filtered tibbles. Use `ungroup` to omit them.

Comment: It's also well documented. Looking at `?select_if` help page, the 4th line is *"The `_if` and `_at` variants always retain grouping variables for grouped data frames."*

Comment: I'd also suggest updating your answer. I think the simplest way (and keeping it more in the `dplyr` ecosystem) is `ungroup()`, rather than casting to data frame for its side effect of ungrouping. This answer will be most useful to other help-seekers if the first mentioned solution is `ungroup()`.